# How to re-render <ui:repeat> using <f:ajax render>

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, uirepeat

I have implemented a list created by a repeater:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{projectData.paginator.list}" var="project">
  <h:outputText value="#{project.title}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

and a Button that filters my list:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{overviewController.filterNew}">
<h:outputText value="Filter List" />
</h:commandLink>
```

So, is there an easy way to render only my repeater after clicking the command link (with AJAX) :-)

---

I tried following:

```
<f:ajax render="repeater">
ui:repeat id="repeater" value="#{projectData.paginator.list}" var="project">
  <h:outputText value="#{project.title}" />
</ui:repeat>
<f:ajax />


<h:commandLink action="#{overviewController.filterNew}">
<h:outputText value="Filter List" />
<f:ajax event="click" render="repeater"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

but that did not work..

---

### Update

```
<h:form>
ui:repeat id="repeater" value="#{projectData.paginator.list}" var="project">
  <h:outputText value="#{project.title}" />
</ui:repeat>

<h:commandLink action="#{overviewController.filterNew}">
<h:outputText value="Filter List" />
<f:ajax event="click" render="repeater"/>
</h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

doesn't work either... Maybe I hav to put the action method (overviewController.filterNew) into the ajax tag?

---

### Update 2

```
    <f:ajax event="click" render="repeater">
    <h:commandLink action="#{overviewController.filterEBus}">
    <h:outputText value="EBusiness" />
    </h:commandLink>
    </f:ajax>
```

Doesn't work either!

---

Maybe it's not possible to rerender a repeater ? is there another element like a div tag or something that can be rerendered???

...

Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe I hav to put the action method (overviewController.filterNew) into the ajax tag? - try, why not?

Comment: Doesn't work either! If nobody sees a mistake maybe there is a jsf/ajax bug?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `<ui:repeat>` itself does not generate any HTML to the output. The `<f:ajax render>` expects an ID which is present in the HTML DOM tree. Put it in a `<h:panelGroup>` with an `id` and reference it instead.

```html
<h:form>
    <h:panelGroup id="projects">
        <ui:repeat value="#{projectData.paginator.list}" var="project">
            <h:outputText value="#{project.title}" />
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:commandLink action="#{overviewController.filterNew}">
        <h:outputText value="Filter List" />
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="projects" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Comment: But for me it seems that this does not work in case of a validation exception. In this case my data is lost.

Answer (score 4):

Yes:

- using Richfaces `<a4j:commandButton reRender="targetId" />`
- using JSF 2.0 [`<f:ajax event="click" render="targetId">`](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/04/learning-jsf-2-ajax-in-jsf-using-fajax-tag/)
- using Primefaces `<p:ajax>`

Answer (score 2):

```
<f:ajax render="repeater">
ui:repeat id="repeater" value="#{projectData.paginator.list}" var="project">
  <h:outputText value="#{project.title}" />
</ui:repeat>
<f:ajax />
```

why did you wrap it with f:ajax? It's redundant in this case.

Make sure that your components are surrounded by `<h:form>` tag

```
<h:form>
<ui:repeat id="repeater" value="#{projectData.paginator.list}" var="project">
  <h:outputText value="#{project.title}" />
</ui:repeat>

<h:commandLink action="#{overviewController.filterNew}">
<h:outputText value="Filter List" />
<f:ajax event="click" render="repeater"/>
</h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Comment: That's what I tried as well. And I surrounded the whole part with h:form tags :-( It just dies nothing -.-

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<ui:repeat id="repeater" value="#{projectData.paginator.list}" var="project">
  <h:outputText value="#{project.title}" />
</ui:repeat>

<h:commandLink>
  <h:outputText value="Filter List" />
  <f:ajax render="repeater" listener="#{overviewController.filterNew}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: `ui:repeat` doesn't support the `id` attribute. Which makes sense since it doesn't represent anything, it's just a flow control tag.

Comment: Ok, so he'll need to wrap it in <h:panelGroup>