# Update a repeater with AJAX in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm trying to update a repeater list with AJAX based on this : [How to re-render <ui:repeat> using <f:ajax render>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547581/jsf-rerender-with-ajax)

But the HTML list is not updated after the first load, even if the ArrayList in the ManagedBean is.

Here is what I have in my xHTML file :

```html
<h:form>
   <h:panelGroup id="messages">
       <a4j:repeat var="mes" value="#{talking.listMessages}">
          <h:outputText value="#{mes.sendTime}">
             <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"/>                                
          </h:outputText>
          #{mes.content}
       </a4j:repeat> 
   </h:panelGroup>
   <a4j:commandLink action="#{talking.testAdd}">
      <h:outputText value="Add Item" />
      <f:ajax execute="@form" render="messages" />
   </a4j:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

In the MB I did this simple action :

```
private ArrayList<Message> listMessages;

public void testAdd() {
  this.listMessages.add(new Message(/* [...] */));
}
```

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Try replacing your `a4j` tags with built-in jsf and facelet ones. I think `ui:repeat` and `h:commandLink` will do the same work. Apart from that I can't see what's going wrong here because your case is very similar to the referenced one.

Comment: Also check that your backing bean is not being rebuilt with the initial values when you perform the ajax request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the RichFaces documentation about [`<a4j:commandLink>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Actions.html#sect-Component_Reference-Actions-a4jcommandLink):

> The  component is similar to the JavaServer Faces (JSF)  component, except that it includes plugged-in Ajax behavior.

Knowing this, the problem is that `<f:ajax>` doesn't work with `<a4j:commandLink>`. You should rewrite your code to this:

```html
<h:form>
   <h:panelGroup id="messages">
       <a4j:repeat var="mes" value="#{talking.listMessages}">
          <h:outputText value="#{mes.sendTime}">
             <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"/>
          </h:outputText>
          #{mes.content}
       </a4j:repeat>
   </h:panelGroup>
   <a4j:commandLink action="#{talking.testAdd}"
      render="messages">
      <h:outputText value="Add Item" />
   </a4j:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Also, make sure you're managed bean is `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: You are right, I mixed too much AJAX components. It works, thank you.